# x86 Assembly Programming: Recursive function is overflowing the stack

Tags: recursion, assembly, x86, att

I am trying to code a recursive Fibonacci program in x86 Assembly (Intel AT&T syntax). I get a StackOverflow error in the form of a segmentation fault. Below is my code:

```
# Function signature:
# int factorial(int n)

.text
    .equ n, 8
    .equ fibMinus1, -4

.global fibonacci
fibonacci:
    # Prologue (prepare the stack frame)
    push %ebp
    mov %esp, %ebp

    # ECX is the non-volatile register which stores n
    movl n(%ebp), %ecx

    # Make space on the stack frame to store fib(n - 1)
    subl $4, %esp

    # If n == 0:
    cmpl $0, %ecx
    # return 0
    je retZero

    # If n == 1:
    cmpl $1, %ecx
    # return 1
    je retOne

    # EDX = fibonacci(n - 1)
    decl %ecx
    push %ecx
    call fibonacci
    movl %eax, fibMinus1(%esp)

    # EAX = fibonacci(n - 2)
    movl n(%ebp), %ecx
    subl $2, %ecx
    push %ecx
    call fibonacci

    # fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2)
    addl fibMinus1(%esp), %eax

    # Epilogue (cleanup the stack frame)
    mov %ebp, %esp
    pop %ebp

    # Return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2)
    ret

retZero:
    movl $0, %eax

    # Epilogue (cleanup the stack frame)
    mov %ebp, %esp
    pop %ebp

    # Return the maximum possible weight of the bags :D
    ret

retOne:
    movl $1, %eax

    # Epilogue (cleanup the stack frame)
    mov %ebp, %esp
    pop %ebp

    # Return the maximum possible weight of the bags :D
    ret
```

This seems strange, considering that I modify the necessary parameters when pushing them onto the stack before the function call, and after each function call, I execute the epilogue sequence to reframe the stack to its proper position such that the proper parameters are retrieved during the next call.

My code models the following Python recursive code:

[image]

Comment: You have an extra epilogue between the two recursive calls. That should not be there. Also, `edx` is of course not preserved across the recursion, so you can't use that to save the result of the first recursion.

Comment: @Jester Since EDX is not preserved across recursion calls, I would need to make space on the Stack for a local variable storing the value of the first recursive call (fib(n - 1)), correct?

Comment: Yes, that would work.

Comment: @Jester In my updated code, I am storing the value of the first recursive call (fib(n - 1)) at 4 bytes below the start of the stack (ESP). However, I always get a very large negative number as the result of my program.

Comment: `fibMinus1(%esp)` is wrong. `esp` is always the bottom (or top, depending) of the stack. You correctly allocated the local with `subl $4, %esp` but that moved `esp` so you should use `fibMinus1(%ebp)` to reference it, as `esp` will again move later.

Comment: @Jester Thanks, everything works now :D!